# Diagonal of parallelogram and parallelepiped

Tags: geometry

> Diagonal — is a line that connects 2 opposite vertices

But for a parallelogram and a parallelepiped definitions of opposite vertices are different.

> Opposite vertices *of a parallelogram* — two vertices that don't lie on a *face*.

> Opposite vertices *of a parallelepiped* — two vertices that don't lie on a *side*.

And we have a conflict. For example, two vertices that lie on a face of a parallelogram are opposite? If we use first definition then an answer is «Yes!» but if we use second definition then an answer is «No!» IMHO, in the context of a parallelogram the answer should be «Yes!» If we want to determinate if two vertices make a diagonal of a face we should determinate if these vertices are opposite in the context of that face (the face is a parallelepiped). But there is an opinion that we shouldn't use the definition of opposite vertices: that confuse, must burn in hell, etc.

What opinion is right? I was looking for an answer but I didn't find.

<sub>Example</sub>

[image: example]

$BG$ connects 2 opposite vertices of this parallelepiped?

<sup>**Note**. English isn't my first language. If you've found mistakes you should fix thoose. After fixing or if this post don't have mistakes you should delete this note. Thank you for understanding.</sup>

Comment: A parallelogram refers to a 2D shape, whereas a parallelepiped refers to a 3D shape.

Comment: @TobyMak and?.. we have a parallelepiped and 2 vertices. we need the definition of a diagonal of a parallelepiped. in this definition are using the definition of opposite vertices, and that definition is differend in the context of a parallelogram and a parallelepiped.

Comment: What you have written does not make any sense to me. You should include a diagram to show us what exactly you mean.

Comment: @TobyMak I don't found a syntax for drawing a 3D shape. could you help me?

Comment: Try [Geogebra 3D](https://www.geogebra.org/3d). I want to know if your definition of opposite for a parallelipiped includes vertices which lie on the same plane, or if they cannot be on the same plane, and lie on the space diagonal (search this up).

Comment: @TobyMak The post updated.

Comment: @TobyMak I'm waiting for your solution: you written these comments not for fun.

Comment: Just because I leave some comments under your post does not mean I *have* to answer you. I do not think your question can be answered at the moment because the definition of "opposite" is too broad. The question is too subjective for Maths SE.

Comment: If you want your question to be answered, check out [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/32652#32652). I really do not see why your question is useful, so if you could tell us more about where this comes from, that would be great.